# "You are absent of cause or excuse"

Tags: grammar, writing-style

This is a lyric from "Achilles Come Down" by Gang of Youths. Is "absent of cause" proper grammar or a stylistic form?

Comment: Lyrics generally get a free pass with regard to grammaticality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a rather obscure expression (***absent of + noun***) but [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=absent%20of%20%2A_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cabsent%20of%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Babsent%20of%20men_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsent%20of%20mind_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsent%20of%20course_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsent%20of%20necessity_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsent%20of%20fear_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsent%20of%20light_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsent%20of%20life_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsent%20of%20color_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsent%20of%20people_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsent%20of%20emotion_NOUN%3B%2Cc0) does find incidences of this use, which seems to be more popular around the beginning of the 1800s.
[image]

Hardly any dictionary includes this use, I could only find:

> While the giant has made efforts recently to elevate quality reporting in its algorithms, most of those ranking decisions are made ***absent of** human judgement*. ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/absent))

One can guess that it is used with the meaning of ***(de)void of***... My advice, enjoy it in the song, but avoid using it in other contexts. There are other more idiomatic ways of saying the same.

This is only a supposition, but it may be an adaptation of the use of ***absent*** as a preposition:

> *preposition* FORMAL•NORTH AMERICAN
> without.
>
> - *Absent* a willingness to negotiate, you can't have collective bargaining. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=absent%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsZgPL4kMxLDHqcbgCE8p3ri3Mh1vA%3A1659694843921&ei=--7sYvjIN8aA8gLVprTgBA&ved=0ahUKEwi4su2Mva_5AhVGgFwKHVUTDUwQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=absent%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCQgjECcQRhD5ATIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMggIABAeEAcQCjIGCAAQHhAHOgQIABBDOgwIABCxAxBDEEYQ-QE6BQgAEIAEOgcIABCxAxBDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUABY0QdgsBBoAHABeACAAWeIAeMDkgEDNC4ymAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz))